# Send bearer + token in request header C++ builder?

Tags: json, api, c++builder, bearer-token, request-headers

I'm working with a C++ application in embarcadero RAD Studio.
I'm trying to access my swagger api https://camur3.treffo.se/api/swagger/index.html to fetch information using the RESTClient, RESTRequest and RESTResponse components.

Now the API is authorized with bearer + token. Right now i can get out the token:[image]

So i've trying to do a new call to the api from another button

```
void __fastcall TForm7::B_NewRequestClick(TObject *Sender)
{

    RESTClient1->BaseURL = "https://camur3.treffo.se/api/users/authenticate/access";
    //Request header + token??
    RESTRequest1->Execute();
}
```

But don't know how to send the token in next request..
Anyone who knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the token in an `Authorization` request header, eg:

```cpp
RESTRequest1->Params->AddHeader(_D("Authorization"), _D("Bearer ") + token);
```

Or

```cpp
RESTRequest1->AddParameter(_D("Authorization"), _D("Bearer ") + token, TRESTRequestParameterKind::pkHTTPHEADER);
```

Or

```cpp
RESTRequest1->AddAuthParameter(_D("Authorization"), _D("Bearer ") + token, TRESTRequestParameterKind::pkHTTPHEADER);
```